# Write a list of dict as consecutive columns to csv

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, csv, dictionary

I am trying to write a list of dict, say:

`list = [dict1, dict2,...,]`

with the following:

`dict1 = {key1: value1, key2: value2,...}`

How could I write each dict into 2 columns, consecutively, into one single csv files? You would have column 1 and 2 belong to key and value of `dict1`, column 3 and 4 contain key and value for `dict2`... and so on?

Comment: you want dict3 in column 5 and 6 ?

Comment: Yes - consecutive dict into the next 2-columns.

Comment: First things first, do NOT call it `list`.

Comment: SO isn't a code writing service and, even if it were, your requirements are not clear. Please review [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this program,Hope it will produce the output you required,

```
import csv

dict1 = {'key11' : 'value11', 'key12' : 'value12', 'key13' : 'value13'}
dict2 = {'key21' : 'value21', 'key22' : 'value22', 'key23' : 'value23'}
dict3 = {'key31' : 'value31', 'key32' : 'value32', 'key33' : 'value33'}

list1 = [dict1, dict2, dict3]

with open('mycsvfile.csv','wb') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    for entry in list1:
        lis = []
        for key,values in sorted(entry.items()):
            lis.append(key)
            lis.append(values)
        w.writerow(lis)
```

**Output :**

```
key11,value11,key12,value12,key13,value13
key21,value21,key22,value22,key23,value23
key31,value31,key32,value32,key33,value33
```

Please let me know interms of any queries.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your list is `l=[{1: 2, 3: 4, 5: 6}, {9: 10, 11: 12, 7: 8}, {17: 18, 13: 14, 15: 16}]`. Start with extracting keys and values from of each dictionary:

```
[l0.items() for l0 in l]
# [dict_items([(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]), 
#  dict_items([(9, 10), (11, 12), (7, 8)]), 
#  dict_items([(17, 18), (13, 14), (15, 16)])]
```

Now, let's combine each list of tuples into a flat list:

```
from itertools import chain
[list(chain.from_iterable(l0.items())) for l0 in l]
# [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 
#  [9, 10, 11, 12, 7, 8], 
#  [17, 18, 13, 14, 15, 16]]
```

The result can be fed directly to a CSV writer.

Answer (score 0):

using itertools chain:

```
import csv
from itertools import chain

dictionary = [{'key1': 'value1'}, {'key2': 'value2'},
              {'key3': 'value3'}, {'key4': 'value4'}]

with open('file', 'w') as fh:
    csv_file = csv.writer(fh)
    csv_file.writerow(chain(*(i for e in dictionary for i in zip(e.keys(), e.values()))))
```

result:

```
cat file
key1,value1,key2,value2,key3,value3,key4,value4
```